# Multiple module maven project Error Could not find artifact

Tags: maven-3

I have a multiple module maven project. I recently changed the snapshot version in each module.

```
Root
 -web-module
    --pom.xml
 -ear-module
    --pom.xml
 -common-module
    --pom.xml
```

After changing the version I am getting below error.

```
Could not find artifact com.kulhade.prj:common-module:jar:2017.08-SNAPSHOT in
in myrepo
```

I have few repositories in my root pom which helps me to get different dependencies. myRepo is one of them.
Please suggest if anyone encountered the similar issue.

Comment: Somehow Intellij-Idea had added some dependencies in my root pom while resolving dependencies in one of the child module. Which was resulting a cyclic dependency and giving error.